# Selecting rows in a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using lines of code that have worked flawlessly before, and for some reason I have not been able to grasp, when reusing these lines, I get no errors, but I don't get the desired output. I'm not sure if it has something to do with the file or something else entirely. Is there a way to debug on python or understand what is going on?

Scenario 1 code:

```
df2 = df.loc[C1['col1'] == '']
print(Blank_cusips)
df.to_excel(r"...folder path...\1.xlsx", index=False)
```

I know for sure 'col1' has blank values, and with this code I intend to extract al rows with blank values in col1. However, I'm getting a blank dataframe.

Scenario 2 code:

```
import datetime

def add_days_to_date(date, days):
    subtracted_date = pd.to_datetime(date) + timedelta(days=days)
    subtracted_date = subtracted_date.strftime("%m-%d")
    return subtracted_date 
def replied_sent_date(date):
    return f"Opened {date} need update {add_days_to_date(date, 15)}"

date = datetime.date.today() 
date_format = date.strftime('%m-%d')

df['col5'] = df.apply(lambda _:" ", axis=1)


df.loc[(df['col1'] != ''), 'col5'] = f"Opened {date_format} need update {add_days_to_date(date, 14)}"
```

When this code is exported I do get the f string on the cells, but I get it for all cells in the column, not just the cells for which "df['col1'] != ' '"

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: `' '` doesn't look like a blank value, there is a whitespace character.

Comment: Already corrected to `''` and I still get no values back

Comment: Hi, in scenario 1, it should be `df["col1"]` instead of `C1["col1"]` and `df2.to_excel` instead of `df.to_excel`.